# Trying to generate just time in string format using strftime from a datetime column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a datetime column in pandas that I'm trying to use to generate a string in HH:MM:SS.fff format. The result that I get from the following code provides the date in YYYY-MM-DD format and then the time in my desired format.  I can't figure out why the following code automatically produces the date along with the time.

```py
print(meta['DATETIME'].dtype)
print(meta['DATETIME'].dt.strftime('%H:%m:%s.%f').str[:-3].values)

# Returns:
datetime64[ns]
['2021-11-15 11:12:48.660' '2021-11-15 11:12:58.660']
```

Comment: Noticed the format string is incorrect. Started with `'%H:%m:%s.%f'` became `'%H:%M:%S.%f'` thanks to @rudolfovic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me:

```py
>>> data = pd.Series([pd.to_datetime('2021/1/1 14:32')]
>>> print(data).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f').str[:-3].values)
['14:32:00.000']
```